# Dagger and Butterknife

Tags: android, dagger-2, butterknife

I am using dagger2 in my app. But when I started project my activities was extended support AppcompatActivity.Now while build I am getting warning via butterknife.

API `'variantOutput.getProcessResources()'` is obsolete and has been replaced with '`variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'`.

To fix this I must upgrade butterknife version from 9.0.0-rc1 to 10.2.0 when I change version butterknife to 10.2.0 I am getting error to build.Because I am not using androidx. error like this:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-70:19 to override.

So I don't know how to fix this issue.If somebody had such kind of error and warning please help me if you fixed it

[image]

Comment: You will need to update to AndroidX to remove that warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrate your project to AndroidX, butterknife 10.2.0 is on androidX.

Answer (score 0):

It literally says what you need to do. Add `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` like this: `<application tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"`

Comment: I did like this again new error occured.Always I try to fix as recommendation and it causes new problems